# Count totals in different ranges on all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make 3 totals. 
Approved, Rejected and Waiting

Each sheet in the workbook has this information in the same columns.

What i have tried so far is below, with various tweaks, but it seems to count wrong and i cannot seem to grasp how i get it right.

```
    Sub test()
Dim WS As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, T1 As Integer, T2 As Integer, T3 As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long
On Error Resume Next

Set rng1 = Range(("B1"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rng2 = Range(("C1"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rng3 = Range(("D1"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


T1 = 0
T2 = 0
T3 = 0

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
        For Each cell In rng1
            If cell.Value = "1" Then T1 = T1 + 1
        Next
        For Each cell In rng2
            If Cells.Value = "1" Then T2 = T2 + 1
        Next
        For Each cell In rng3
            If Cells.Value = "1" Then T3 = T3 + 1
        Next
    End With
Next

MsgBox "Godkendte: " & T1 & "--- Afviste: " & T2 & "--- Afventer: " & T3

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you counting how many 1's in the range? Do your ranges only contain 1's and 0's?

Comment: You can do this with a formula - is there a reason you're using VBA?

Comment: @CallumDA - Yeah, only counting the 1's as that's what they input where needed.

Comment: @MacroMan Because of the high amount of sheets, and the datarow number vary a lot too. It also needs to be in various workbooks, selected by the user at the start, but i got that part sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified a fair bit. If you find yourself writing variable names with numbers at the end, you're probably better off using an array

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim v(1 To 3) As Variant

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            v(1) = v(1) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), 1)
            v(2) = v(2) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Range("C1"), .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), 1)
            v(3) = v(3) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Range("D1"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), 1)
        End With
    Next

    MsgBox "Godkendte: " & v(1) & "--- Afviste: " & v(2) & "--- Afventer: " & v(3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks a lot! 
Needed it to be VBA as the user is prompted to select the file it needs to count in. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are defining your Ranges outside of the loop, so :

- those Ranges are defined on the ActiveSheet when you run your program
- it's always the same Ranges that you count over and over inside the loop

You also had `Cells.Value` instead of `Cell.Value`, I changed the variable to be more distinct!

---

Corrected code :

```
Sub test()
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Dim RgCell As Range
Dim T1 As Integer, T2 As Integer, T3 As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NumberToCount As Integer
Dim StringToCount As String

NumberToCount = 1
StringToCount = CStr(NumberToCount)

T1 = 0
T2 = 0
T3 = 0

For Each wS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wS
        Set rng1 = .Range(("B1"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rng2 = .Range(("C1"), .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rng3 = .Range(("D1"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With 'wS

    For Each RgCell In rng1
        If RgCell.Value = NumberToCount Or RgCell.Value = StringToCount Then T1 = T1 + 1
    Next RgCell
    For Each RgCell In rng2
        If RgCell.Value = NumberToCount Or RgCell.Value = StringToCount Then T2 = T2 + 1
    Next RgCell
    For Each RgCell In rng3
        If RgCell.Value = NumberToCount Or RgCell.Value = StringToCount Then T3 = T3 + 1
    Next RgCell
Next wS

MsgBox "Godkendte: " & T1 & "--- Afviste: " & T2 & "--- Afventer: " & T3

End Sub
```

Comment: A perfect example of why it's best to fully qualify ranges! +1

Comment: Cheers, this seemed to help, but the counting is still off.
It seems to only count on the active sheet and multiply it by 4... I tried tweaking values in that, and make the whole workbook a lot slimmer for testing purposes

Comment: @Thiil : Are you sure that your `1`s are all stored as text in Excel?

Comment: @MacroMan : Exactly my thought when I saw the OP! ;)

Comment: And thanks for the help guys - not super experienced on this field, trying my best to learn, understand and search before i post :)

Comment: @Thiil : Try the edit, it'll test both strings and number! ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again!